# Splunk - How could I change entire bar graph color based on token?

Tags: colors, bar-chart, splunk

I want to change bar graph color based on token value.

For example, when I get token name "fruit",I want to change etire bar graph color depend on token like this.

- **Apple** : Red (0xfc4103)
- **banana** : Yellow(0xf5db36)
- **grape** : Purple(0xa536eb)

(When the token data is "Apple", the entire graph color become Red-0xfc4103-)
So I write down code using "charting.fieldColors".

```
<panel>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <query>
              .......
              | eval paint_chart = case("$fruit$"=="Apple","0xfc4103", "$fruit$"=="banana","0xf5db36", "$fruit$"=="grape","0xa536eb")
              | chart count by amount_DT
              | rename count AS "Number of fruit"
              ...
          <earliest>-10d@d</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
        </search>
        ....
        <option name="charting.fieldColors">{paint_chart}</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
```

But it's not working at all. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: To process fields outside of a query, use a results token.  `<option name="charting.fieldColors">{$results.paint_chart$}</option>`

Comment: @RichG Thank you for your help, but it still not working. It seems that splunk didn't recognize **$results.paint_chart$** or **$result.paint_chart$**